# Show that there exists an infimum for this set of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness, lipschitz-functions

Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-empty set. Consider that the set $C_S=\{\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n|\gamma\text{ is continuous }, S\subseteq\gamma([0,1]), \gamma \text{ is Lipschitz}\}$ is non-empty and define:

$$\|\gamma\|_{\text{Lip}}=\sup_{s\neq t} \frac{\|\gamma(s)-\gamma(t)\|}{|s-t|}$$

for each $\gamma\in C_S$. I want to show that there exists $\gamma_\star\in C_S$ such that $\|\gamma_\star\|_{\text{Lip}}=\inf \{\|\gamma\|_{\text{Lip}} | \gamma\in C_S\}$.

My first attempt was to try to show, using Arzelà-Ascoli and such, that the set $C_S$ is compact in $C([0,1],\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the $\|f\|_{\infty}$ metric, and then try to construct a continuous function $F:C_S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (with the obvious candidate being $F(\gamma)=\|\gamma\|_{\text{Lip}}$, although I don't know if it is continuous) such that I can guarantee the infimum property.

However, the problem I found is that I cannot prove that $\{\|\gamma\|_{\text{Lip}} | \gamma\in C_S\}$ is bounded, hence there can be arbitrary big Lipschitz constants, what makes it difficult to prove that $C_S(t)=\{\gamma(t)|\gamma\in C_S \}$ is bounded and also that $C_S$ is closed.

I ran out of ideas for the moment, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if your set of Lipschitz norms is unbounded above, since you're looking for an infimum, and we clearly have the bound from below given by 0.

So take a minimizing sequence, i.e. a sequence of curves $\gamma_k$ such that
$$
\| \gamma_k \|_{lip} \downarrow \inf\{ \| \gamma\|_{lip}: \gamma\in C_S\}.
$$
You can always find this sequence by definition of infimum. They will have uniformly bounded norms, and your Arzela-Ascoli argument will give the result.